# CGDisplayCopyAllDisplayModes() does not give a complete list of available modes

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-lion, screen-resolution

I've been trying to write a simple app that resets display resolution for an iMac and a connected projector to 1024x768, 85 Hz and 32bit color.

When the projector is directly connected to the mac with VGA or HDMI, the CGDisplayCopyAllDisplayModes() function gives a list of modes which includes the settings I want to apply. But my college uses Extron VGA wall box thing to connect VGA wires to projectors, which leads to CGDisplayCopyAllDisplayModes() giving a much smaller (only 800x600 and 640X480) list of modes. Also, the name of the display when using the wall box is just VGA Display as opposed to Np-511 or whatever the name of the projector is. The weird thing is that System Preferences->Display shows a 1024x768 setting even then and lets me apply it too.

Is there any way to either get a larger list of modes for the projector, create a 1024x768 mode from scratch and apply it (I've already confirmed that the projector supports it) or simply make System preferences choose that mode for me? I've already written an applescript to do the latter but the disply preferences changes according to the projector connected so I need a more general solution.

Looking forward to your help! I've added some code I used and can include more of it if it'd help.

```
 CGGetOnlineDisplayList (MAX_DISPLAYS, displays, &numDisplays); // to get list of display ids
 // ... now iterating over list of displays
 CFArrayRef modeList = CGDisplayCopyAllDisplayModes (displays[i], NULL);
```

Comment: It is true that CGDisplayCopyAllModes() won't give you a list of all modes available on a display. It does not give you HiDPI modes either, for example, although they can be found in the system pref pane. There is an SPI that will presumably give you the modes you are looking for, but then you will not be able to publish your software on the AppStore. There is a [blog post](http://garethjenkins.com/2012/07/01/investigating-a-high-resolution-retina-utility-for-macbook-pro-1x-and-2x-modes/) that has some info on it and the link to an open source tool that uses the SPI.

Comment: The code linked from the blog is exactly what I need. Thank you!

Comment: This issue here appears to be at the root of a bug causing Java applications to fail with an `IllegalArgumentException` claiming an “invalid display mode”. I filed [MACOSX_PORT-805](http://java.net/jira/browse/MACOSX_PORT-805) for that, and will be interested to see what solutions the JDK developers will find for this.

Comment: @bkafle62 The link which is given above, for the blog post, is no longer available. Do you still have that code which was there on the blog? I am looking for exactly the same thing. I would appreciate any help on this. Thanks!